# watch a file while performing other actions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, file-watcher

I am implementing a winform application that is supposed to do the following:

1. OnLoad, open an XML file reading required information while watching for any new changes to the file (incoming new information)
2. A timer performing certain actions based on the nature of the provided information from the XML file. Please note that the nature of the action depends on the content of the XML file

What is the best way to achieve this? Two threads? Async? Some starting point would be much appreciated.

Comment: Start researching [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I know how to use FileSystemWatcher to monitor a file change. I'm not sure how communicate the result to an going action?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this structure. Firstly you read XML file and configure your custom `MyConfigurationClass` object. After this point you can configure `FileSystemWatcher` object. And finally, you can configure your task schedular object with your desired time interval.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyConfigurationClass configuration;

    string filePath = @"./some.xml";
    FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        // First read action action for 
        var task = Task.Run(() => ReadXML());

        InitializeComponent();

        FileWatherConfigure();

        TimerConfigure(task.Result);
    }

    private void FileWatherConfigure()
    {
        fileWatcher.Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        fileWatcher.Filter = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        fileWatcher.Changed += FileWatcher_Changed;
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void TimerConfigure(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        timer.Interval = configuration.TimeInterval.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        SomeClass someClass = ReadXML();
        // Do whatever you want file change
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        try
        {
            // Schedule Operation
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        timer.Start();

    }

    private SomeClass ReadXML()
    {
        // Read file and do what ever you want
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    // Data from XML
}

public class MyConfigurationClass
{
    public TimeSpan TimeInterval { get; set; }
}
```